# Determine which of my for iteration has the smallest error

Tags: python

I am working on a project in python that picks the best predictor from the ones I created and I would like to plot this data vs the actual data. I encountered a problem where after I use my function I do now which is the best predictor, but I want the same function to be able to graph it as well.

```
predictor = [(f"Median {x}", create_median_predictor(x)) for x in (30, 60, 90, 120)] + [(f"Average {x}", create_average_predictor(x)) for x in (30, 60, 90, 120)]
best = float("inf")
best_predictor = None
for name, predictor in predictor:
    error = predictor_test(data, predictor, length, test_data_start)[0]
    print(name, error)
    if error < best:
       best = error
       best_predictor = name
```

With this I know that for example, average for size of 60 is the best predictor, however, it is returned to me as a string, so I cannot dynamically call it inside this function to be able to graph it.
Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  Do you need the best predictor in addition to it's name?  If so, why not also save the best predictor in the if condition i.e. `best_predictor_func = predictor`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I did not know that I can just save the best function

Comment: Yes, in Python everything is an object (i.e. ints, floats, strings, functions) so you can assign any of them to a variable.  So with `best_predictor_func = predictor`, you can use best_predictor_func as a function.

Answer (score 0):

As [@DarrylG suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856742/determine-which-of-my-for-iteration-has-the-smallest-error#comment114667430_64856742), in Python, everything is an object. So functions are objects that you can assign to a variable.

It gives:

```py
predictor = [
    (f"Median {x}", create_median_predictor(x))
    for x in (30, 60, 90, 120)
] + [
    (f"Average {x}", create_average_predictor(x))
    for x in (30, 60, 90, 120)
]
best = float("inf")
best_predictor = None
best_predictor_func = None  # <- Here
for name, predictor in predictor:
    error = predictor_test(data, predictor, length, test_data_start)[0]
    print(name, error)
    if error < best:
       best = error
       best_predictor = name
       best_predictor_func = predictor  # Saves the best predictor function

print(f"Got best error {best} with predictor {best_predictor} and function {best_predictor_func.__name__}")
```